# Having trouble correctly manipulating state in Om app

Tags: clojurescript, om

I'm having trouble manipulating state in an Om app. Specifically, I can't figure out how to remove items from a list.

Here's a demonstration of my folly. It's a simplified app that's broken. https://gist.github.com/rerb/29d10959e71ba1e31e8e

Two buttons are displayed. When pressed, they should remove themselves.

After deleting the first item, I get this error when trying to delete the second:

```
   Uncaught Error: No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type cljs.core/PersistentArrayMap: {:id 2}
```

If I delete the second one first, I get this error when trying to delete the first:

```
   Uncaught Error: Assert failed: Can't put nil in on a channel
```

What simple thing am I missing? I'm Einstellung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `remove` returns a sequence, not a vector. Your state went from `{:buttons [{:id 1} {:id 2}]}` to `{:buttons ({:id 1})}`. By using `into` after `remove` you solve your problems:

```clj
(fn [buttons]
  (into [] (remove #(= button-id (:id %)) buttons))))
```

Note: I tried this with [Chestnut](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut) and it seems to work. Also, if you are beginning with Om avoid using core.async in the beginning. It is a great complement to Om but using both while learning was too much for me to handle.